# How to use the last state of a variable as the next state in Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, lstm

For learning purposes, I want to build my own LSTM model in Tensorflow. The problem is, how to train is in a way that the states at a certain timestep get initialized using the states from the previous timestep. Is there a mechanism for this in Tensorflow?

```
class Lstm:

    def __init__(self, x, steps):
        self.initial = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, size])
        self.state = self.initial
        for _ in range(steps):
            x = self.layer_lstm(x, 100)
        x = self.layer_softmax(x, 10)
        self.prediction = x

    def step_lstm(self, x, size):
        stream = self.layer(x, size)
        input_ = self.layer(x, size)
        forget = self.layer(x, size, bias=1)
        output = self.layer(x, size)
        self.state = stream * input_ + self.state * forget
        x = self.state * output
        return x

    def layer_softmax(self, x, size):
        x = self.layer(x, size)
        x = tf.nn.softmax(x)
        return x

    def layer(self, x, size, bias=0.1):
        in_size = int(x.get_shape()[1])
        weight = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([in_size, size], stddev=0.1))
        bias = tf.Variable(tf.constant(bias, shape=[size]))
        x = tf.matmul(x, weight) + bias
        return x
```

Answer (score 0):

@danijar - you may want to look at the 'Variables' section of [this page](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/get_started/basic_usage.html) for a simple example of how to maintain state across calls to a subgraph.